# How do I start app on boot and allow run like whatsapp

Tags: android, server, broadcastreceiver

i want when boot run app server allow for receive message any time

without showing application

this code problem when boot show Notification twice only
but i want receive message any time

Is this "android:exported" important, What used

code AndroidManifest

```
        <service
        android:name=".appService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:enabled="true">
        </service>

    <receiver
        android:name=".ServiceStarterBoot"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

code BroadcastReceiver

```
public class ServiceStarterBoot extends BroadcastReceiver  {

private Context context ;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context1, Intent intent) {
    this.context = context1;

    if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Intent serviceLauncher = new Intent(context, appService.class);
        context.startService(serviceLauncher);
    }}
```

code Service

```
public class appService extends Service {     
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    lood();
} 
  @Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    //return mBinder;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "onStartCommand", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}


private void lood(){
    SystemClock.sleep(3000);

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            boolean p= true ;
            while(p) {
                SystemClock.sleep(5000);
                showNotification();
            }
        }
    };
    Thread mythread = new Thread(runnable);
    mythread.start();
}
```

please help 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have to make your service sticky:

Service.START_STICKY

then it is infinite and restarts itself when killed by OS for any reason.

It even starts itself when booting OS and app is NOT opened by user.

Best regards.

Comment: after boot showing Notification twice only ,What do I do?

Comment: this is normal behavior. your service has the task to make a thread. the service does it and then the task is finished. you have to implement a listener to the service. for example a state change listener. when a state changes. the service will get the state and fires your method.

Comment: There is no problem when the program is opened and the server is running,
The problem is when a server is running in boot

Answer (score 0):

pseudo code:

```
onStartCommand(..){
```

...

//e.g. wifilisterner
Wifilistener WF = new Wifilistener(Interface yourInterfaceCallBackMethod);

}

something like this.